# Lambda notation in NLP

Tags: nlp, lambda-calculus

I should do semantics analysis and use lambda notation for following sentences

I need help for:
What is lambda notation for definite and indefinite determiner?

`Anna drew a red panda.`

For `a` I used `exist x: lambda p: p(x)` am I right?

For `The` I used `exist just one x: lambda p:p(x)`

What is lambda notation for `to` before verb as in `to scratch`

`The red panda that Anna drew liked to scratch itself.`

For `What did Anna do to her panda`
I considered this notation for do: `lambda z: lambda y: lambda x: do(x,y,z)` am I right?

Answer (score 2):

You say "lambda notation", I guess you mean formal semantics 
of natural language, with representations in lambda calculus.

For proper nouns, a classical way is to use lambda P . P(a) 
where a is a constant denoting the entity.

For the indefinite "a", the classical way is lambda P. lambda Q (exists x: P(x) and Q(x))
but different definite give rise to different semantics.

Definite descriptions in general are more tricky as they depend on the context of the utterance.

I would advise you to read: 
http://www.coli.uni-saarland.de/projects/milca/courses/comsem/html/
for a more complete picture.